# How To upload Android mobile and Android TV application with same package name in play console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, android-tv

Hello everyone I am trying to upload mobile and tv applications together with the same package name
I have uploaded both packages with different version numbers but having the same package name
I have uploaded both assets and fill all the required information.

like in Disny+hotstar the same for both mobile and tv.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use same package name for Android Mobile and Android TV apps for play store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66457339/can-i-use-same-package-name-for-android-mobile-and-android-tv-apps-for-play-stor)

Comment: Yes I have seen that and do the same 
like Min SDK version check 
lean back and touch use feature 
and the package name is also the same but when I upload the application then only mobile application show.

Comment: And, how do you expect the TV app to be shown?

Comment: Like I am searching mobile application on the play store it showing there but when I search on Tv then it is not showing there, and from the web when I click on install it is showing that TV is not a supported device and only mobile device is supported.

Comment: Have you enabled TV as the release type in Play console's [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64927370/8244632)?

Comment: I have checked this but I don't get the Advance option in the android play console. Can you please guide me there?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Thank you bro application is now published for both platforms the main issue was n advanced setting application type.

Comment: @khushbu Thanks for reminding me but your solution should be directed towards the questioner.